# How to delete multiple files matching two specific lines in Linux

Tags: linux, grep, find

I have 1,000+ files and I would like to remove in all of them the following two lines that appear one after another.

```
<noscript>
</noscript>
```

I can't remove them individually because some files have actual content in between those tags.

Is there a way to do it recursively?

If that would help, I could add something specific in between and then remove those.

Example:

```
<noscript>
REMOVE-ABOVE-AND-BELOW
</noscript>
```

The issue with that would be that some files have it inline.
Example:

```
<noscript>REMOVE-ABOVE-AND-BELOW</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it in two commands.

**sample.txt** (my test input file)

```
<tata>
    awef
    awef
    awef
</tata>
<noscript>
</noscript>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
<noscript>
REMOVE-ABOVE-AND-BELOW
</noscript>
<noscript>REMOVE-ABOVE-AND-BELOW</noscript>
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
<noscript></noscript>
ccccccccccccccc
<something>
    ok
    ok
    ok
</something
ddddddddddddddd

eeeee
```

**script**

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '!/<noscript>.*<\/noscript>/' sample.txt >tmp.txt
sed '/<noscript>/,/<\/noscript>/d' tmp.txt
mv tmp.txt sample.txt
```

- the `awk` removes lines with "ANYTHING".  So with tags on 1 line.
- the `sed` removes everything between "" on one line, and "" on another line.  It removes the tags as well.

---

Result

```
<tata>
    awef
    awef
    awef
</tata>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccc
<something>
    ok
    ok
    ok
</something
ddddddddddddddd

eeeee
```

---

This processes one file.  Since you want to process multiple files, you can use

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    PROCESS CODE HERE
done
```

This is taken from https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001